# Retrieving Last Boot Time Stamp In C

Tags: c, system, clock, uptime

I've been able to retrieve the uptime value from `/proc/uptime` (which is in seconds). However, I need to retrieve the last boot time stamp using C. (I cannot use `system(...)` function to call uptime.)

For example, when I run the `uptime` command, the value I get is:

```
15:31:35 up 2 days,  4:14,  3 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.05
```

I need that first part: `15:31:35`. Is there a built-in C function that can get me this?

Comment: `strace uptime` will show you what `uptime` does, and then you can do that. Hint: `open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/proc/uptime` and read it. The first number is the uptime in seconds.

Comment: I know..I have that value. That's easy. I just don't know how to get the exact HH:MM:SS time stamp. If I convert the seconds in the file, to HH:MM:SS, it will give me total hours and minutes and seconds the computer has been on, instead of the actual time stamp of when the computer started, ya know what I Mean?

Comment: @JakeZ So then is your question "How can I determine what time it was some number of seconds ago?"? If so, read up on `time(3)` and `localtime(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading /proc/uptime is good.

Or you can use `FILE *fp = popen("uptime", "r")` and read from fp the string you want.

That's a little more portable. ( By that I mean different unix's like MacOS ).

Oh, I just saw your lack of "system" requirement. Never mind.